# popover and yii2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii2

I cant create popover in yii2.

Button doesn't do anything

JS

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

Connect JS

```
$this->registerJsFile('/assets/js/popover.js',  ['position' => yii\web\View::POS_END]);
```

PHP/HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger"
data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="Popover Here">
Click to toggle popover
</button>
```

**Reslove**

Thanks dev.mraj

```
$this->registerJsFile('/js/boot/bootstrap.js',['position' => yii\web\View::POS_END,'depends'=>['yii\web\JqueryAsset']]);
```

When create List need use

```
 $('#test_div').html(options).find('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please stick to English in your posts.

Comment: Please, include more details. Any errors? 
ошибки есть? Файлы подключил? Как угадать?

Comment: @JohanWillfred
ошибок нет. просто кнопка ничего не делает. вот здесь только JS подключил 
 $this->registerJsFile('/assets/js/popover.js', ['position' => yii\web\View::POS_END]); 
Вот перечень того что загрузил фреймворк
<script src="/assets/popover.js"></script>

<script src="/assets/jquery.js"></script>

<script src="/assets/yii.js"></script>

<script src="/assets/yii.activeForm.js"></script>

Comment: It is hard to say where is a problem. Try to execute `$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()` in browser console on page with popover and probably you`ll see errors

Comment: @JohanWillfred
do this and have this error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).popover is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:30`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$this->registerJsFile('/assets/js/popover.js', ['position' => yii\web\View::POS_END,'depends'=>['yii\web\JqueryAsset']]);
```

Comment: stop working my previous script
`$this->registerJsFile('/assets/js/hideshow.js',  ['position' => yii\web\View::POS_END]);`

and now have problem
`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).popover is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (popover.js:2)
    at fire (jquery.js:3187)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3317)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:3536)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery.js:3552)`

Comment: do you website live website where we can see it?

Comment: access only by ip (for my test version where i do tests)

Comment: Unless you share more nobody  will be able help you... :)

Comment: popuover is loading before jquery... thats code i've given is correct please check you may have issue because of other things you did

Comment: popover.js has above code.. where is popover function declared.. you didnt included popover plugin js fiel

Comment: how include in yii2(i`m newbie)

Comment: resolve /vendor/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap/BootstrapAsset.php add `  public $js = [
        'js/bootstrap.js',
    ];`
but how do it locally, not in whole site (Bootstrap broke old styles)